# On the meanings of INTONE

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I have always had doubts as to the exact meaning of *intone*. Here is how Vocabulary.com defines the word—

> utter monotonously and repetitively and rhythmically

**AND**

> speak carefully, as with rising and falling pitch or in a particular tone

Am I the only one who thinks these two meanings convey two opposite sense of the word? And if that's so— Shouldn't *intone* be a contronym? (I doubt I have ever read about *intone* being a contronym, though)

Answer (score 1):

“Am I the only one ... ?” I take to be an unanswerable rhetorical question.

The definitions you quote seem to be consistent if we understand “rising and falling” in the sense I believe it to be intended: repeatedly rising and falling. {Up, down, up, down, up, down, ...} rather than simply {up, down, finish}. The variation from up to down may be only small, as in (for example)

> Intone = Say or recite with little rise and fall of the pitch of the voice.
>
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/intone)